# What verb to use with the old meaning of "an execution"?

Tags: expressions, verbs

Before *execution* settled into its modern meanings of "running a piece of software" and "state-organised killing", it was a much more general term for acting and doing. In this now outdated context, one could "do an execution on" something or someone, meaning roughly the same as "fix it", "do a number on it" or "lick it into shape".

I'm just not sure that *doing* is the right verb. Does one "*do* an execution" on something, "*work* an execution" on something, "*wreak* an execution" on something, or should it be some other verb I haven't thought of?

Comment: It should probably be *execute*. Wills are still executed by executors.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.  I don't recall ever encountering "execute" in the sense of "beat something into shape".

Comment: Other than murder, to execute is to perform a function.  You can execute a ballet step, a somersault, @AndrewLeach's will, or a computer program's compiled code.  If you run a program, you are executing its machine code.

Comment: 'Carry out' (more conversational than 'perform' and less highfalutin' than 'execute') works in most cases. 'Do an execution of one's work' is unacceptable if not strictly ungrammatical.

Comment: Several early examples of this meaning in the OED are in the form *put in(to) execution*. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: The question headline is simply wrong. It's utterly commonplace, today, to say "executed a ballet step", "executed a triple spin" or whatever.  A handful of specialist "software engineers" might (in vague circumstances) use it in the software sense (which is, utterly, the same as the "ballet step" sense). There are also other commonplace uses of the word (such as the legal "will" sense mentioned.)  Regarding the "how do you say do a .." question; it's like asking ... "'*Do a* triple spin; how do we say do a do a ?"

Comment: I need some examples, not being familiar with the old meanings and usage of *execution*. // My go-to formal alternative for do/make is *to complete*, for example, "complete a functional behavioral assessment."

Comment: @Fattie: The question headline is exactly right, because I wasn't looking for an alternative verb to use in place of 'execute', nor looking for any answers on how to use the verb 'execute'. I could get those from a thesaurus or dictionary, if I didn't already know them. Instead, my specific question was the one described in the title. As you can see, someone understood it and answered it, and it turns out that my instinct for "do ... execution" was right.

Comment: Hi @EditingFrank - all i would say is that it's bizarre you refer to it as the "old" meaning.  That meaning is the normal, commonplace meaning.  Indeed, what you refer to as the "new" meaning (state-killing) is simply obscure.  It would be used once in a thousand times compared to the ordinary, everyday meaning.  (Regarding the technical usage by a handful of software engineers, it's totally irrelevant.)

Comment: It's entirely possible that either I fully fail to understand this question, or, it's all just bizarre.  :)    As was instantly mentioned buy Andrew, "It should probably be execute. Wills are still executed by executors."  What more is there to see here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never encountered countable *execution* (that is, *executions* or *an execution*) except in the sense of an instance of executing the order of a court of law (including an execution of the death penalty); and the only other uses reported by [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed03arch#page/n1149/mode/2up) are of a sense obsolete since the early 18th century: “a performance” of an operation, work or piece of music.

> **1628** Look to your actions, to your doings, to your executions and performances.

*OED* gives no citation of this with *executions* or *an execution* as object of a verb.

What you do still encounter from time to time is *do execution*, used originally of military actions with the sense "inflict destructive effect"

> ...an adder, when she doth unroll
>   To do some fatal execution —Shakespeare, *TitA*

This has been later extended in a figurative (and I think largely jocular) sense to “the effect of arguments, personal charms, etc.”

> Black eyes, which might have done some execution had they been placed in a smoother face. —Thackeray

One might, I suppose, speak of “an” execution, in the sense of a performer’s manner or excellence of performance on some particular occasion—

> Sartorius gave us the A-minor with a polish and an execution far above his usual mediocrity of expression.

but that sort of *execution* is not done or performed, it is a quality of the performance.

Comment: Funny thing Stoney; I wonder if I'm missing something here or on a different planet.  My kid is a top dancer. It's totally commonplace that I say to her or I hear:  *"That was a fantastic execution"*.  Regarding the plural, I couldn't put my hand on my heart and say "I said this recently", but it would seem utterly, totally, commonplace and unremarkable to hear "look at those executions" or "all the executions were perfect" or "on Saturday your costume sucked and three of your executions sucked as well".  Maybe the examples I just gave in this comment, ***are not*** what you're talking about??

Comment: Note that for example the first quoted sentence (apparently from 1628??) seems utterly normal, everyday, and contemporary to me.  "Nice executions last night".

Comment: @Fattie - I'd say that the uses you find natural have the sense in my last three paragraphs: the quality or technical competence of the performance rather than the event or fact of performing, which appears to be what OP has in mind.

Comment: Hmm.  In my sentence "That was a fantastic execution" I am using "execution" as a straight out simile for the nouns dance, performance, night, show, step, sequence.  I think I'm not smart enough for this QA  :)

Answer (score 0):

"execute" is a perfectly good verb. Why not use it rather than agonize over somehow using its nominal form with some other verb?

Comment: @Fattie Good point, one with which I basically agree.  I will delete my comment.

Comment: Of course I know it's a perfectly good verb. I was merely satisfying my curiosity about the much rarer, obsolete usage in which its nominal form was used with another verb.